# Moment JS Wrong Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```js
let time = moment();

console.log(
  time
  .year(2021)
  .week(34)
  .day('monday')
  .format('D MMM YYYY'),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Displays `16 Aug 2021` but it should be `23 Aug 2021` - why?

Works well if the year is 2020, 2019, etc but fails on year 2021

Comment: I think it should be week 35 not 34

Comment: The problem is that there are two ways of calculating week numbers one using the way how defined in ISO 8601 standard. USA and other countries however use a different way of determine the start of first week of a year. You need to check what momentjs uses. And if that one matches your target locales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch `.week` to `.isoWeek` and it works.

```
const moment = require("moment");

let time = moment();

console.log(
  time
    .year(2021)
    .isoWeek(34)
    .day('monday')
    .format('D MMM YYYY'),
);
```

More info from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68842658/6254964

Answer (score 1):

**It is not wrong**. If you look at the `2021` calendar, the `34th` week is `15 - 21 August`. You specified it as `Monday`.So it's `16 Aug 2021`.

**Note:** Start of a week is `Sunday` (ISO Standard).

Comment: That's only true in some countries, for me the 34th week is the 22-28

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? Checking the calendar here and asking google says that the 34th week in 2021 starts at 22th of August.

Comment: @t.niese That's why I mentioned that the start day of the week is `Sunday`. Because that's the standard

Comment: The ISO specification (8601) uses for the week numbering calculations weeks starting at Monday.  `week` does not follow the iso standard.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because of your locale.
the `week` method uses your locale to determine which week is the first of the year (which would mess up your week calculation, putting you one week behind).

For more, read [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I added an answer for this specific situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/68842967/6254964